# Troubles with playing music Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried to make a command to play music using youtube_dl. My discord.py version is 1.5.1
Here is my code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Wait for the current playing music end or use the 'stop' command")
        return
    await ctx.send("Getting everything ready, playing audio soon")
    print("Someone wants to play music let me get that ready for them...")
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
    voice.volume = 100
    voice.is_playing()
```

But I get this output:

```py
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'guild'
```

The Error is in this line `voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)`
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have **1** voice client per guild, so simply do:

```py
voice = ctx.guild.voice_client
# or
voice = ctx.voice_client
```

Reference:

- [`Guild.voice_client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice#discord.Guild.voice_client)
- [`Context.voice_client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=voice#discord.ext.commands.Context.voice_client)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [DiscordUtils](https://pypi.org/project/DiscordUtils/) module. It has a class called DiscordUtils.Music